# Displaying Hierarchical custom taxonomy

Tags: php, taxonomy

I bought I real estate theme, I need a child category for Community custom taxonomy so i set the Hierarchical to True. But when I tried displaying it in my page the Community comes first before the sub community. This is what it displays:

> "Business Bay, Business Tower, Dubai, UAE"

instead of

> "Business Tower, Business Bay, Dubai, UAE"

Business towers is the child, Business bay is the parent. It should be child first before the parent right?

can you please help me.

[image: here is the screenshot when i display the community]

Here is the code:

```
    $communitylabels = array(
            'name' => __( 'Community', 'contempo' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Community', 'contempo' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Communities', 'contempo' ),
            'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Communities', 'contempo' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Communities', 'contempo' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent', 'contempo' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent', 'contempo' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Community', 'contempo' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Community', 'contempo' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Community', 'contempo' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Community', 'contempo' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Communities with commas', 'contempo' ),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Communities', 'contempo' ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Communities', 'contempo' )
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'community', 'listings', array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $communitylabels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'community' ),
        ));
    }

    if ( ! function_exists( 'community' ) ) {
        function community() {
            global $post;
            global $wp_query;
            $terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $wp_query->post->ID, 'community', '', ', ', '' ) );
            echo esc_html($terms_as_text);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code when i call the custom taxonomy:

```
      // Title
        case 'listing_title' :

           echo '<h2 class="marT5 marB0">';
                ct_listing_title();
            echo '</h2>';

        break;

        // location
        case 'listing_city_state_zip' :

            echo '<p class="location marB0">';  
            community();
            echo ', ';     
                city();
                echo '';
                country();

            echo '</p>';
```

Comment: Actually, the parent comes first, your query is right

Comment: Hello, I edited my post can you please check again? i add some more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sort your terms by hierarchy, you can use `wp_get_post_terms()` instead.

It's usage is similar to `get_the_term_list()`. Take a look at this simple example:

```
wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy->name, array( 'orderby' => 'term_id' ) );
```

I think we can safely assume that the parent will mostly have a lower ID of its childs (if not manually changed), so this will do the trick. But if the post belongs to several parents, then this will break again.

Take a look at the relative [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms) page for more information about this function.